# How to disable CakePHP4 DebugKit creating the huge tmp/debug_kit.sqlite file

Tags: php, cakephp, production-environment, cakephp-4.x, cakephp-debug-kit

I've developed an app with CakePHP 4.4.11.  In production environment, I set `debug` to false in `app_local.php`.

```
'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', false), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
```

The app is working fine as expected, however, I noticed the `tmp/debug_kit.sqlite` file has been created and getting bigger even though DebugKit is not in use.

How can I completely disable or safely remove DebugKit?  I did some research, but I couldn't find about it.

Answer (score 2):

If the file keeps growing, that means that the plugin is still being loaded. Out of the box, the default application template will only load the plugin in debug mode, so maybe you don't have that set up in your app:

```php
if (Configure::read('debug')) {
    $this->addPlugin('DebugKit');
}
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.1/src/Application.php#L59-L64**

Another possible problem could be that the config file isn't being loaded. Out of the box, the `app_local.php` file overwrites settings from the `app.php` config file, but it's only being loaded when explicitly configured in the bootstrap:

```php
if (file_exists(CONFIG . 'app_local.php')) {
    Configure::load('app_local', 'default');
}
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.1/config/bootstrap.php#L90-L92**

Also there could of course be an environment variable named `DEBUG` be present which is set to `true`, being it a real environment variable, or one from a `.env` file.

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/4.4.1/config/.env.example#L17**